# ArcGIS Flex API: Convert a screen point to a MapPoint

Tags: apache-flex, gis, esri, arcgis-server

Using the ArcGIS Server Flex API, is there a way to convert mouse coordinates on the screen or the a map control to spatial coordinates in the map? It seems like there's functionality to convert map points to screen points, but a function for converting in the other direction seems weirdly absent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [this method](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisserver/apis/flex/apiref/com/esri/ags/Map.html#toMap%28%29) should help

Answer (score 0):

hector: You really should ask this as a question, or you could look into the documentation. Method [toScreen()](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisserver/apis/flex/apiref/com/esri/ags/Map.html#toScreen%28%29) is just what you want.